# Oracle SQL - Update Duplicate with a max value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, duplicates

I'm looking for an UPDATE statement where it will update a row that have duplicated timestamp and update only the row that have a MAX value at the duration column, I can utilize in Oracle SQL or PL/SQL.

Here is an example TABLE1 to work with:

| ID | TIME | DURARTION | VALID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12:30 | 6 | - |
| 2 | 12:35 | 2 | - |
| 3 | 12:35 | 5 | - |
| 4 | 12:35 | 9 | - |

Result expected:

| ID | TIME | DURARTION | VALID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12:30 | 6 | TRUE |
| 2 | 12:35 | 2 | FALSE |
| 3 | 12:35 | 5 | FALSE |
| 4 | 12:35 | 9 | TRUE |

I tried this query:

`update TABLE1 set VALID = 'TRUE' where  id not in (select  max(id) from TABLE1 group by TIME)`

but it update only the row with the max ID, I couldn't figure figure out how to update the row with the max DURATION.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use case clause to update value with TRUE or FALSE.

```
update TABLE1
set tru_false = case when (TIME, duration) in (select time, max(duration) from TABLE1 group by time)
                then 'TRUE'
                else 'FALSE'
                END
```

[Here is a small demo that I hope it will help](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8d0a99fb207e3a0106ec23f6529b6c2e)